# How to style a specific nav menu item?

Tags: menus, css

I have a site, which now have a new registration form and I want to highlight it by blinking the menu item. you can see the site [here](http://www.cgrc.info/).

I wan to blink "Registration for seminar" item. I am using Polyon theme.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

To address a specific menu item in your stylesheet you can either use its `id` attribute (here: `li#menu-item-230`) or add a CSS class. I like the second option, that is more flexible.

Sample code for your theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_65375_class_by_title', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Make the title a CSS class.
 *
 * @wp-hook nav_menu_css_class
 * @param   array $classes
 * @param   object $item
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_65375_class_by_title( $classes, $item )
{
    $new_class = mb_strtolower( $item->title );
    $new_class = str_replace( ' ', '-', $new_class );
    $new_class = sanitize_html_class( $new_class );
    $classes[] = $new_class;
    return $classes;
}
```

A menu item with the title *Registration for Seminar* has now the CSS class `registration-for-seminar`. You can make it blinking, bold, whatever … in your stylesheet now:

```css
.registration-for-seminar
{
    text-decoration: blink;
}
```

`blink` will not work in Webkit browsers. For JavaScript workarounds ask on Stack Overflow.

Another way to add CSS classes is the native field for menu items in `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`:

[image]

Comment: Nice drawing style! +1

Comment: Is there a way to access those "CSS Classes" in the code? How would I do it?

Comment: @ShaneKm [Ask a new question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).